# Data Extension or Data Export log

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-export, data-extract

I would like to see who has been exporting data from our data extensions in the past year but I am not sure if this functionality is available in Marketing Cloud.
I have tried with Audit Trail (I have enabled the advanced one) but I am not able to see this specific information, it only shows changes in permissions and users.

Does anyone know how to access this info on an account level?

Thank you so much in advance!

Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is not accessible in any way in UI nor in Audit Trail. The Audit Trail is under constant development, and I will suggest you to raise this with your Account Executive from Salesforce, to ask this feature to be added, by creating a Voice of Customer record. If sufficient number of requests supports same feature, there is a higher probability of this coming into the development roadmap and being prioritised.